# How to get the the result of batch file to C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd, mining

I am currently struggling with bringing existing data in batch file to C# window form

The whole objective is getting a result lively from batch file to C# rich text box but I am keep getting failure of doing it.

The procedure works like click button->run batch file secretly->C# gets data lively->display in rich text box

I was successful to run a batch file but it runs in another new CMD causing hanging problem during debugging.

I would like to know whether anyone can wrote me a code to overcome such problem. Hope for the best answer

```
        ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo();
        Process process = new Process();
        cmd.FileName = @"cmd";

        cmd.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmd.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.CreateNoWindow = true;

        process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        process.StartInfo = cmd;
        process.Start();
        process.StandardInput.Write(@"cd C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Claymore's Dual Ethereum+Decred_Siacoin_Lbry_Pascal AMD+NVIDIA GPU Miner v11.0" + Environment.NewLine);
        process.StandardInput.Write(@"EthDcrMiner64.exe -allpools 1 -epool asia1.ethereum.miningpoolhub.com:20535 -ewal AJStudio.AJStudio001 -epsw x -esm 2" + Environment.NewLine);
        process.StandardInput.Close();

        string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("[result info]" + DateTime.Now + "\r\n");
        sb.Append(result);
        sb.Append("\r\n");

        richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Close();
```

Comment: literally!!, You should show some code for reproduce which is your problem.

Comment: Oops my mistake, forgot to post the code. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1):

To get real-time feedback from Process, use OutputDataReceived and ErrorDataReceived events. Something like this:

```
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

process.OutputDataReceived += Process_OutputDataReceived;
process.ErrorDataReceived += Process_ErrorDataReceived;

process.Start();

process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

process.WaitForExit();

private void Process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data == null) return;
    log("ERROR: " + e.Data);
}

private void Process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data == null) return;
    log(e.Data);
}
```

Comment: If the exe file which runs in CMD starts, the procedure is like c#->CMD-> opening the exe file isn't it? In this case due to the code process.WaitForExit(); form gets into hanging status since the EXE program is the crypto currency mining program thus it produces live time data. Sorry for my lack of knowledge but please help

Comment: Run the method that runs the process in a separate thread - you can search for Task.Factory.StartNew or async await pattern. The former i find conceptually simpler, but it's a matter of taste mostly. What you have to remember with parallel threads, is that you cannot access GUI objects directly from non-main threads. So, in your code the richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString(); assignment would produce cross-thread violation error. To get around that, look up examples of how Invoke and BeginInvoke methods can be used for cross-thread UI updates.